# Loop skips to the last iteration

Tags: java, android, loops

I'm writing code for a maths quiz app that's supposed to ask addition questions using random numbers. This part works, the problem is when I use a loop. The loop jumps to the end and when I use the debugger I see that the onclick method is never run until the last iteration, because the first question is never displayed and no input is entered. I have tried placing the loop in different places and used different loops. The funny thing is I even used a do loop which should ask the first question and then loop but it's always the last question that's displayed.

This is the main code

```
public void generateAdditionQuiz() {
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz);
    TextView text_view_question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_question);
    TextView text_view_feedback = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    do{
        final String question = addition();
        text_view_question.setText(""+question);
        text_view_feedback.setText("score " + questionsAnswdCrrct + "question # " + questionsMAX);
        Log.i("My Acy", "questions " + questionsMAX);
        Button buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText answerInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer_field);
                // parse input string to int
                int answer = Integer.parseInt(answerInput.getText().toString());
                String[] arrayQuestion = question.split("\\+");
                // parse string array to int array
                int[] parsedQuestion = new int[arrayQuestion.length];
                int questionSum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayQuestion.length; i++) {
                    parsedQuestion[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrayQuestion[i]);
                    questionSum += parsedQuestion[i];
                }
                if (answer == questionSum) {
                    questionsAnswdCrrct++;
                } else {
                    //text_view_feedback.setText("Incorrect");
                }
            }
        });questionsMAX++;
    }while(questionsMAX<=2);
}
```

Comment: You are setting the same pair of question/feedback `TextView`s again and again in the loop?

Comment: Yes, so a new question is displayed every time and to update the score.

Comment: But wouldn't a later question overwrite the first one?

Comment: you only want to update QuestionsMax after the question is answered. What you have will update it right away and fly through.

Comment: Somewhere outside what we see questionsMax is initialized to 1, right? But if you want to allow multiple quizzes it would make more sense to declare and initialize it inside the method.

Comment: but if you increment QuestionsMax only on the click (as you should), you will need to add logic to avoid printing the question header and stats repeatedly.

Comment: probably cleanest to check if it is the last question you just asked, and if not do the next question asking inside the onClick (and then put asking the first question outside the loop entirely). It feels like the loop should be empty and all the repeated action should happen onClick.

Comment: @jingx I guess that's whats happening, because as I said only the last question is displayed.